# ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor threads remain when completed

Tags: java, multithreading

The routine myProcessToRun() needs to be executed 100 times but there needs to be about a second delay between each execution.

The following FOR Loop is used in conjunction with the ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor object.

```
for (int n=0; n<100; n++)
{
    final ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor executor = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(1);
    executor.schedule(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
          myProcessToRun();
      }
    }, (n+2), TimeUnit.SECONDS);                            
}
```

This actually works fine but the threads still remain.
Using JVisualVM the number of Threads increases by 100 threads when the routine is executed. When the routine finishes, the 100 threads still remain.

Clicking the "Perform GC" button doesn't clean them up so Java still believe they should exist.

How do these threads get cleaned up using an example like above?

---Edited---

I noticed the ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor was being instantiated within the Loop which was a terrible idea. After moving it outside the LOOP the threads created weren't so bad.

After attempting to implement the solution there was unexpected behavior.

```
final ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor executor = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(10);               
for (int n=0; n<100; n++)
{
    //final ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor executor = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(2);
    executor.schedule(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
          doAddNewCondSet();
      }
    }, (n+2), TimeUnit.SECONDS);                            
}
try 
{
    executor.shutdown();
    if (!executor.awaitTermination(400, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
        executor.shutdownNow();
} catch (InterruptedException e1) 
{
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

With the modified code, it would immediate stop all the processes with the shutdown and nothing was executed. 
With the executor.shutdown(); commented out and just using the awaitTermination(), the program just hung and after a few minutes, all the processes kicked off at the same time without delay which resulted in errors.

I suspect my implementation was wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of ways that you can do this. You can view some of them here:
https://www.baeldung.com/java-executor-wait-for-threads

My personal favorite is the CountDownLatch:

> Next, let’s look at another approach to solving this problem – using a
>   CountDownLatch to signal the completion of a task.
>
> We can initialize it with a value that represents the number of times
>   it can be decremented before all threads, that have called the await()
>   method, are notified.
>
> For example, if we need the current thread to wait for another N
>   threads to finish their execution, we can initialize the latch using
>   N:

```
ExecutorService WORKER_THREAD_POOL 
  = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(2);
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    WORKER_THREAD_POOL.submit(() -> {
        try {
            // ...
            latch.countDown();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
    });
}

// wait for the latch to be decremented by the two remaining threads
latch.await();
```

Comment: Thanks. It is my first time using the ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor  object and had no idea it fell into the "Executor" category area. Also, I noticed that I should not be instantiating the ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor  within the Loop. By doing so outside the Loop and setting the size to 10 it does significantly help to limit the Threads, but your answer should help to clean them up.

Comment: I tried adding the following code, but it seems to kill the entire process immediately. If the shutdown() call is removed, it seems to still wait to process everything at once without the delay which then causes my routine to fail because there is no delay.  Is the implementation wrong? 
    try 

 {
  executor.shutdown();
  if (!executor.awaitTermination(400, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
   executor.shutdownNow();
 } catch (InterruptedException e1) 
 {
  e1.printStackTrace();
 }

Comment: You can try the CountDownLatch approach, as it looks fit for your purpose. Just make sure you use the right number as a parameter on `new CountDownLatch(int n)`.

Comment: Since these objects are new to me, the CountDownLatch didn't seem as straight forward as the other but I will give it a try.